# richfaces ajax calls

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, jboss7.x

I'm having problems running my JSF application after migration to JBoss7. I'm using JSF2.0 and Richfaces 4.2.2-Final.

After deploying application to JBoss7, most of the Ajax calls from Richfaces components stopped working and application is acting really weird. We are having two jQuery libraries defined which worked on JBoss6.1 :

Although I see in Firebug both are loaded, when ajax call is invoked, I'm getting that jQuery TypeError related to invoked function, for example : *$(".accordionWrapper").accordion is not a function*

Strange thing is that actions for some of the Richfaces components on UI is working fine. 
Can anyone advise how to resolve this issue?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems some weeks ago, with this exact same version of RichFaces.
I'm not sure, but I think that they were related to the RichFaces issue [RF-12084](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12084).

In my case, I only solved the problems after switching to `f:ajax` from the previous `a4j:commandLink` and `a4j:ajax`.

In that RF issue, someone in the comments suggests switching to JSF 2.1.8 because of [JSF-2347](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2347), so you may try that before messing with your code.